# Restoring from Time Machine on Mac without video card

Tags: network, time-machine, ssh, mac-pro

I’ve got a Mac Pro 5,1 with an Nvidia P600 (Pascal) video card, running the Nvidia Web Drivers. One of the internal disks is its Time Machine volume.

At some point it looks like automatic system updates overwrote the drivers, and the video card stopped working. Mac seems to boot correctly, I’ve been able to access it from a MacBook via Target Disk Mode.

I do not have another video card that will work in this Mac.

Is there a way I can restore the Mac Pro via Time Machine remotely?

I have seen various threads about using Screen Sharing but this was not enabled before the video card issue.

Is there a way to log into the Mac Pro via the Terminal if I connect the MacBook directly to an Ethernet port? I don’t think I can connect with it over WiFi as sharing was turned off, but I can see if it shows up on the network.

If so, what would I then need to do to 1) connect and log in and 2) restore from Time Machine from the command line? Step by step instructions for a command line n00b please :)

Thanks very much!

Comment: I’m not sure which OS you’re on, are you using the right web drivers? https://9to5mac.com/2017/09/27/nvidia-pascal-drivers-high-sierra/

Comment: Yup. Rolled back to the pre-January version of Sierra (Not HS) and reinstalled the appropriate web driver for that build - nada. It could be the card, I am going to test it in a PC to double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You could treat either the whole machine or just the system drive as an external HDD and attach it to your MacBook.

Attach your Mac Pro in TDM (target disk mode) to your MacBook. Boot into the Mac Pro’s system from your MacBook. Repair what you need to do.

1. Connect both computers.
2. Shut them down.
3. Power on the target Mac in TDM by holding the T key.
4. Power on host Mac with Alt/Option key pressed until you see MacOS boot manager.
5. Choose the target’s system disk
6. Boot
7. Repair graphic drivers, etc.

Comment: Ok! I was under the impression that this wouldn’t work because these were two different Macs, IE Sierra on my Mac Pro would not boot my MacBook Pro, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: Well, this solution does work for booting into the Recovery partition on the target-disk Mac and restoring a Time Machine image to the boot drive. Sadly, this didn't solve my video-card issues, but it's a useful tip for future reference!

Comment: High Sierra 10.13.3 implemented a lot of changes to the graphic system. It is quite probable that the web driver stopped working. Do a thorough web search on the issue, contact Nvidia to check if this is a known issue, restore to a point in time before the last system update. In this order...

Comment: It’s currently restored to 10.12.6 Sierra 16G29, not High Sierra, and I reinstalled the matching web driver package and restarted; nothing. I am running some software that at the time was not cleared for HS, so I never upgraded. Now that 10.13.4 has extensive support for AMD cards I’m going to try that.

Comment: There is also the possibility that the problem is not software, but hardware. Maybe the card is defective. Good luck.